# samba4 domain member server: users can't see share list, instead they are prompted for a samba password

Tags: linux, samba, samba4

We need to figure out why windows domain users are being prompted for a password when accessing samba server.  They can see the server under Microsoft Windows Network, but they can not see the share list because when they click on the server's name, they get a password dialogue.

The dialogue is the problem.  That should not show up.  I'll offer this in-case it helps: A domain login is not valid.  Again, I do not need this to work, but a user with a configured local samba password can not authenticate either (setup with `smbpasswd`).

At one point, I had removed an extra share in smb.conf and restarted the services `nmb,smb,winbind` and it started working.  I do not recall making any other changes.  Later, I did a reboot to see if it were stable, and it has not allowed user in to see the shares since.

It was actually working for a while, it was letting people in to see the shares and even let them into there folders (as authorized by using Active Directory security group) as designed..

My setup is the following: 
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/Domain_Member

I have temporarily disabled the firewall.  Once fixed, I did include firewall rules and use some commands from this guide: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba

This is my main configuration with validation performed by `testparm`:

```
# testparm 
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Processing section "[public]"
Processing section "[accounting]"
Processing section "[developer]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_DOMAIN_MEMBER
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
    workgroup = MYWORKGROUP
    realm = MYWORKGROUP.COM
    server string = Samba4 Server
    security = ADS
    kerberos method = dedicated keytab
    winbind enum users = Yes
    winbind enum groups = Yes
    winbind use default domain = Yes
    winbind nss info = rfc2307
    idmap config MYWORKGROUP:range = 500-40000
    idmap config MYWORKGROUP:schema_mode = rfc2307
    idmap config MYWORKGROUP:backend = ad
    idmap config *:range = 70001-80000
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[public]
    path = /mnt/public
    force group = domain users
    read only = No

[accounting]
    path = /mnt/accounting
    valid users = accounting
    force group = accounting
    read only = No

[developer]
    path = /mnt/developer
    force group = developer
    read only = No
```

/etc/krb5.conf

```
# cat krb5.conf 
[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MYWORKGROUP.COM
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    forwardable = yes

[appdefaults]
  pam = {
    debug = false
    ticket_lifetime = 36000
    renew_lifetime = 36000
    forwardable = true
    krb4_convert = false
  }
```

Suffixed winbind after files (note, some systems use compact instead of files):

```
# egrep winbind nsswitch.conf
passwd:     files winbind
shadow:     files winbind
group:      files winbind
```

I did not see any SELinux Samba security features that needed to be on:

```
# getsebool -a | grep samba
samba_create_home_dirs --> off
samba_domain_controller --> off
samba_enable_home_dirs --> off
samba_export_all_ro --> off
samba_export_all_rw --> off
samba_portmapper --> off
samba_run_unconfined --> off
samba_share_fusefs --> off
samba_share_nfs --> off
sanlock_use_samba --> off
use_samba_home_dirs --> off
virt_use_samba --> off

# getsebool -a | grep smb
allow_smbd_anon_write --> off
```

Although, I have to start `nmbd` in a script as the service start script is throwing an error (`bind failed on pipe socket /var/run/samba/nmbd/unexpected: Address already in use`) on this platform.  It worked at one point when I had simply started it using the command: `nmbd` (two messages appear in log.nmbd: `nmbd ...started`, `standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option`).  So, here is my restart script:

```
# cat smb-restart 
service nmb restart
nmbd
service smb restart
service winbind restart
ps -eaf|egrep "mbd|winbind"
```

Everything appears to be running:

```
# ps -eaf|egrep "mbd|winbind"
root     25057     1  0 12:38 ?        00:00:00 nmbd
root     25071     1  0 12:38 ?        00:00:00 smbd
root     25087     1  0 12:38 ?        00:00:00 winbindd
root     25091 25087  0 12:38 ?        00:00:00 winbindd
root     25092 25071  0 12:38 ?        00:00:00 smbd
root     25512 25087  0 12:45 ?        00:00:00 winbindd
root     25513 25087  0 12:45 ?        00:00:00 winbindd
root     25514 25087  0 12:45 ?        00:00:00 winbindd
root     25579 25087  0 12:45 ?        00:00:00 winbindd
```

Not sure if this is required, but I have added pam winbind commands here:

```
# cat /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac 
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authok
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_krb5.so
session     optional      pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
```

I have successfully joined the domain and I can see domain users and groups via `wbinfo -u` and `wbinfo -g`.

I can list and re-new the service principal with `kinit Administrator@MYWORKGROUP.COM` and `klist`.

I think winbind is loaded fine:

```
# ldconfig -v | grep winbind
libnss_winbind.so.2 -> libnss_winbind.so.2

# locate libnss_winbind
/lib64/libnss_winbind.so
/lib64/libnss_winbind.so.2
/usr/lib64/libnss_winbind.so

# locate libnss_wins
/lib64/libnss_wins.so
/lib64/libnss_wins.so.2
/usr/lib64/libnss_wins.so
```

I have a user called jcalfee, but the `id` command does can not find them:

```
# wbinfo -u|egrep jcalfee
jcalfee
# id jcalfee
id: jcalfee: No such user
```

I am, however, able to `chgrp` using a domain group.

```
chgrp "domain users" /mnt/public
```

My host file contains a line like this, I was required to put the smb-host fully resolved name first on the 127.0.0.1 line:

```
127.0.0.1   smb-host.domain.com samba-host localhost ....
```

This is how I setup a new share directory in SELinux, this has been working:

```
function mkdir_samba_share {
  path=${1?directory path}
  set -o xtrace
  mkdir -p "$path"
  semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "$path(/.*)?"
  restorecon -R "$path"
  chmod 770 -R "$path"
  chgrp "domain users" "$path"
  ls -ldZ "$path"
  set +o xtrace
}
```

I added a keytab (this will warn if your smb.conf does not contain a global kerberos method).

```
net ads keytab create -U Administrator%password
```

Comment: Are the client machines using credential manager to store the login for the mount perhaps? This has burned me once, when the users domain account password was changed, somehow on some machines a "net use" was done so then the stored credential was being referenced.

Comment: Not sure, but I tested with my machine and the password has not been changed recently.  You are on to something though, I have since turned on log level 3 and discovered these samba errors that occur when I try to browse the shares from windows: `sam_logon returned ACCESS_DENIED.  Maybe the trust account password was changed and we didn't know it. Killing connections to domain ....` and `Authentication for user [jcalfee] -> [jcalfee] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: Is the domain trust intact? `net ads testjoin` will test whether or not the server is joined to the domain successfully. Worth checking, but not sure that this is the silver bullet given you're getting user and group information from the domain.

Comment: # net ads testjoin
`Join is OK`

Answer (score 2):

Undoubtedly it's a authentication mechanism failure of sorts. 
I assume Kerberos is working for you ?

```
kinit administrator@MYWORKGROUP.COM
```

and

```
kinit some_valid_user@MYWORKGROUP.COM
```

Afterwards check

```
klist
```

for the two authentication tokens should show up. If not, please post back the answer. I've seen a bunch of possible faults, but let's rule them out one by one.

Comment: I ran both command and authenticated as our administrator and a user.  I see one Default princapal: some_valid_user@ACCESSRXS.COM then a Valid starting / Expires / Service principal string (so, I assume that is the two you were looking for).

Comment: Ok. Next, although it might be a no brainer. still ... permissions on share/home directories. Do they match on users/ group that the user is accesing them ?

Comment: I did test it with no shares at all, one share, and left in-place the 3 shares above that had worked previously.